# Is there any way to disable k8s rescheduler?

Tags: kubernetes

I don't want `k8s` to transfer any `pod` to another `node` even the node lost.Because i use `hostPath`,if the pod `rescheduled`,the data will lost.

Is there any way to disable `rescheduler`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to disable rescheduler.

But you can limit this pod to specific node via [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector), or you can use [nodeName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.8/#podspec-v1-core).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    env: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/hostname: yourNodeName
```

Note: nodeName will ignore the node which is cordon(kubectl cordon) and has taint.